# Grafana - Derived fields in Loki data source with multiple capture groups

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

[image]

I'm trying to add a derived field that consist of multiple parts. The help text in Grafana suggests that it should be possible to access multiple capture groups, but all I can find is the `${__value.raw}` variable. Are there other undocumented variables to access other capture groups?